# URL config error Django

Tags: python, django, urlconf

I have a link

```
 a href="editYou/{{costumer.slug}}"
```

and URL parttern

```
(r'editYou/<?P(costumerSlug>.*)/$', 'editYou'),
```

that points to method

```
def editYou(request, costumerSlug):
```

but Django shows an error:

```
The current URL, profile/editYou/es, didn't match any of these.
```

How you help me to find what is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong, it should be

```
r'editYou/(?P<costumerSlug>.*)/$'
#         ^^^^
#   not   <?P(costumerSlug>.*)
```

Comment: It may well be he imports this url using `(r'^profile/', include('app.urls'))`

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert, may, but the problem is not with it.

Answer (score 2):

It may be better to name your urls like:

```
(r'editYou/(?P<costumerSlug>.*)/$', 'editYou', name="edit"),
```

Then in your templates, you could use:

```
 a href="{% url edit costumer.slug %}"
```

Comment: You mean in template? `a href="{% url edit costumer.slug %}"`